# Drawing a path with a line in OpenLayers using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers

I have seen the examples presented [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/draw-feature.html) of how to draw a line but the examples only show how to do it with the mouse, by clicking.

What I want to do is **draw the line manually using JavaScript given a list of Longitude and Latitude coordinates**.

The reason I cannot work on the source provided in the link above is because they are only calling `activate` on the feature, and then let the user point and click on the map.

Has anyone ever drew a path on an OpenLayers map programatically?

What I want to do is exactly this: http://openspace.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/openspace/example4.html, but without using OpenSpace.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You would need to make use of the [LineString](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.9/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/LineString-js.html) object

Here is an example:

```
var lineLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Layer"); 

map.addLayer(lineLayer);                    
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path));                                     
var points = new Array(
   new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon1, lat1),
   new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon2, lat2)
);

var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);

var style = { 
  strokeColor: '#0000ff', 
  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
  strokeWidth: 5
};

var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, style);
lineLayer.addFeatures([lineFeature]);
```

Assuming `map` is your map object and `lon` and `lat` are float values.

Comment: I had to use `new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());` instead of just `new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon1, lat1)` as I had wsg84 coordinates

Comment: Good sample. The DrawFeature is actually not needed, the line "map.addControl(....DrawFeature...);" can be omitted.