# Draw a line between two coordinates in OpenLayers 4

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to draw a line between two coordinates in OpenLayers (OL) 4. I have been looking for documentations on The Internet but most of them only for OL 2 ([example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765224/draw-line-between-two-points-using-openlayers) , [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735944/drawing-a-path-with-a-line-in-openlayers-using-javascript)) or 3 ([example3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888181/openlayers-3-simple-linestring-example)).

I took the [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html) from the OL website and add my own code. In this case I am using LineString:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.4/ol.css" type="text/css">
            <style>
          .map {
            height: 400px;
            width: 100%;
          }
            </style>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.4/ol.js"/>
            <title>OpenLayers example</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>My Map</h2>
            <div id="map" class="map"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var map = new ol.Map({
                    target: 'map',
                    layers: [
                      new ol.layer.Tile({
                        source: new ol.source.OSM()
                      })
                    ],
                    view: new ol.View({
                      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
                      zoom: 5
                    })
                });

                //example coordinates
                var lonlat = [33.8, 8.4];
                var location2 = [37.5, 8.0];

                //create the line's style
                var linieStyle = [
                            // linestring
                            new ol.style.Style({
                              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: '#d12710',
                                width: 2
                              })
                            })
                          ];

                //create the line       
                var linie = new ol.layer.Vector({
                        source: new ol.source.Vector({
                        features: [new ol.Feature({
                            geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(lonlat, location2),
                            name: 'Line',
                        })]
                    })
                });

                //set the style and add to layer
                linie.setStyle(linieStyle);
                map.addLayer(linie);

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

However, the line does not appear on the map.
This is my [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50zwv8bu/17/). What's missing on my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert your coordinates using `ol.proj.fromLonLat`

```js
var lonlat = ol.proj.fromLonLat([33.8, 8.4]);
var location2 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.5, 8.0]);
```

You also need to provide `new ol.geom.LineString` an array of points

```js
new ol.geom.LineString([lonlat, location2])
```

You can see [my derived example with the fixes](https://jsfiddle.net/jdrucvqg/) based on your Js Fiddle

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!